# TensorFlow (tf.nn.convolution) Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, anaconda, conv-neural-network

I have the following error:

```
File "/home/mohandsamro/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2856, in conv2d
x = tf.nn.convolution(input=x,

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'convolution'
```

Any help on how to add `nn.convolution` to the module tensorflow?

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: how did you install keras?

Comment: pip install git+git://github.com/fchollet/keras.git

Comment: for tensorflow its tf.nn.conv2d() not tf.nn.convolution

Comment: @Steven
the same error :(
    # With 4d inputs, tf.nn.convolution only supports
    # data_format NHWC, so we transpose the inputs
    # in case we are in data_format channels_first.
    x = _preprocess_conv2d_input(x, data_format)
    padding = _preprocess_padding(padding)
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(input=x,
                          filter=kernel,
                          dilation_rate=dilation_rate,
                          strides=strides,
                          padding=padding,
                          data_format='NHWC')
    return _postprocess_conv2d_output(x, data_format)

Comment: I'm sorry but the reply above is really hard to read. Anyways conv2d doesn't have a parameter called "dilation_rate" so unless the question is updated with more code it will be difficult to help.  You only provided the error and no code to go off of.

Comment: @Steven
i am sorry for comment it's hard to read as you said . it's my first time to ask on stackoverflow . So, i still have the problem and i tried to change tf.nn.convolution to tf.nn.conv2d but nothing changed ?

Comment: What I'm saying is I don't know what the rest of your code looks like so I can't help you without you posting more information.  You can always update your original question with more information which is more readable instead of replying in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The Anaconda Keras package package uses an older version of TensorFlow that is missing some features that Keras expects.  Install the `keras-gpu` package via Anaconda and it will install `tensorflow-gpu` as a dependency, which is a newer version (1.0.1 currently).